# Problems on jQuery hide() and show()

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is my way to hidden the #edit: There is a loading image in body, when the device is ready, it hides $edit and show loading image. when finish actions in getDetail, hidden #load and show #edit.

However, now the problem is, when opening the page, both load and edit are showed, and it works normally after getDetail function.

How should I modify the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        $('#edit').hide();
        getDetail();
    }

</script>
```

js

```
function getDetail() {

        $('#load').hide();
        $('#edit').show();  


}
```

html part

```
    <div id='load'>
    <img src="loading.gif" 
    style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">
    </div><!-- /load -->


    <div id='edit'></div>
```

**Extra Question ** Do I need to `return false;`  in last line of getDetail()? Because all my javascripts are put in a js file. getDetail() is the first function. after running this function, i found that other functions are not work, even a simple on click function to alert something, those functions can only work if put the script in inline style in body.

ps. fixed some copy and paste error

Comment: Make sure to wrap with [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Also, why is your closing <script> tag half way in between the javascript?

Comment: make sure you are not adding `<script>` tags into your external .js file

Comment: i do not have any $(document).ready() . any impact if i have not wrap with it?

Comment: @HUNG if the code is in the HTML file then yes

Comment: If you don't wait for document.ready, there might not *be* an `#edit` element to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify

```
<div id='edit'></div>
```

to

```
<div id='edit' style="display:none;"></div>
```

And also remove the line:

```
$('#edit').hide();
```

It does not have any effect as it is getting shown immediately after being hidden.

Comment: it works, thanks. so does it mean that if an object want to be hidden when loading the page, it is not recommended to use hide()?

Comment: It cannot work without removing the syntax error ... or was it a copy/paste problem? If yes, please adjust your question accordingly

Comment: `hide` does the same thing dynamically, however you were calling `hide` immediately before calling `show`, so it didn't had any effect. The issue with `hide` is that you can call it only after loading page, and directly specifying CSS display style will initially hide the element, without waiting until the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error

There are extra closing brackets inside the getDetail() method. Syntax errors will not only affect this part of the code, they will break the whole script.

Then you should initially hide the `#edit` element using CSS

```
#edit {display: none;}
```

which renders the statement to hide this element useless. Just remove the part `$('#edit').hide()`

And: You shouldn't close the `<script>` tag before the end of your Javascript code.